# Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, error, custom-button

I need help with the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getno_cart_button() on a
>   non-object in
>   /var/home/hifi-studio_at/www/app/design/frontend/default/theme582/template/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml
>   on line 134

This error occurs only in the compare-list. I made an Attribute called "no_cart_button", if it is checked, the product does not show the "Cart-Button" any more, but instead a "Anfrage (Ask)" linking to a Contact-Page. On all other lists and grids it does work. But why no here?
This is the code I used:

```
<!-- // Warenkorb in Anfrage verändern // Start // -->
                <?php   if($_product->getno_cart_button()){ ?> <div class="add-to-cart"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Anfrage') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onClick="parent.location='/kontakt'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Anfrage') ?></span></span></button></div> <?php }
                                        else { ?> <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>', true)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p> <?php } ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                <!-- // Warenkorb in Anfrage verändern // ENDE // -->
```

This Error also occurs only with Products that have this attribute. Others don't show the cart button nor the error.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**The full code:** compare/list.phtml

```
 ?>
    <div class="page-title title-buttons">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Compare Products') ?></h1>
        <a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;" class="link-print"><?php echo $this->__('Print This Page') ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php $_total=$this->getItems()->count() ?>
    <?php if($_total): ?>
        <table class="data-table compare-table" id="product_comparison">
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                    <col width="1" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <col width="<?php echo floor(100/$_total); ?>%" />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php if ($_total>2): ?>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <?php $_i=0 ?>
                    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                        <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <td class="a-right"><a href="#" class="btn-remove" onclick="removeItem('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getRemoveUrl($_item) ?>');" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Remove This Item')) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a></td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        <?php endif ?>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="product-shop-row top">
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>
                    <a class="product-image" href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-top') ?>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <tr class="product-shop-row bottom">
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>
                    <?php if($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <!-- // Warenkorb in Anfrage verändern // START // -->
                        <?php   if($_product->getno_cart_button()){ ?> <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Anfrage') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onClick="parent.location='/kontakt'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Anfrage') ?></span></span></button></p> <?php }
                                else { ?> <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button> <?php } ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
<!-- // Warenkorb in Anfrage verändern // ENDE // -->
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $_attribute): ?>
            <tr>
                <?php $_i=0 ?>
                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                    <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                        <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_attribute->getStoreLabel() ?></span></th>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <td>
                        <?php switch ($_attribute->getAttributeCode()) {
                            case "price": ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-' . $_attribute->getCode()) ?>
                                <?php break;
                            case "small_image": ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" />
                                <?php break;
                            case "date":
                                echo substr($this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute),0,10);
                                break;
                            default: ?>
                                <div class="std">
                                    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute), $_attribute->getAttributeCode()) ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php break;
                        } ?>
                    </td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="add-to-row">
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-bottom') ?>
                    <!-- // Warenkorb in Anfrage verändern // START // -->
                        <?php   if($_product->getno_cart_button()){ ?> <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Anfrage') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onClick="parent.location='/kontakt'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Anfrage') ?></span></span></button></p> <?php }
                                else { ?> <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button> <?php } ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                    <!-- // Warenkorb in Anfrage verändern // ENDE // -->
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item);?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Close Window')) ?>" class="button" onclick="window.close();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Close Window') ?></span></span></button>
        <span class="please-wait" id="compare-list-please-wait" style="display:none;">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Please wait...')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Please wait...')) ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?>
        </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        decorateTable('product_comparison');

        /**
         * Send remove item request, after that reload windows
         */
        function removeItem(url)
        {
            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                parameters: {isAjax: 1, method: 'POST'},
                onLoading: function(){$('compare-list-please-wait').show();},
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    $('compare-list-please-wait').hide();
                    window.location.reload();
                    window.opener.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
<?php else: ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and the code of a working list.phtml:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>

<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="note-msg-empty-catalog">
        <h3><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></h3>
        <?php echo $this->__('This is a custom CMS block displayed if category is empty.') ?><br />
        <?php echo $this->__('You can replace it with any custom content.') ?>

    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(210); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <div class="list-left">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                                            <div class="desc std">
                            <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-right">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <!-- // Warenkorb in Anfrage verändern // Start // -->
                        <?php   if($_product->getno_cart_button()){ ?> <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Anfrage') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onClick="parent.location='/kontakt'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Anfrage') ?></span></span></button></p> <?php }
                                else { ?> <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button> <?php } ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                    <!-- // Warenkorb in Anfrage verändern // ENDE // -->
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist tooltips"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare tooltips"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
            <div class="label-product">             
                <?php if($_product->getData('neu')){echo '<span class="neu">'.$this->__('neu').'</span>';  }?>
                <?php if($_product->getData('neu_ab')){echo '<span class="neu_ab">'.$this->__('neu_ab').'</span>';  }?>
                <?php if($_product->getData('sale')){echo '<span class="sale">'.$this->__('Sale').'</span>';  }?>
                <?php if($_product->getData('aktion')){echo '<span class="aktion">'.$this->__('Aktion').'</span>';  }?>
                <?php if($_product->getData('vorfuehrbereit')){echo '<span class="vorfuehrbereit">'.$this->__('vorführbereit').'</span>';  }?>
                <?php if($_product->getData('season')){echo '<span class="season">'.$this->__('season').'</span>';  }?>
            </div>

        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid row">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?> col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <div class="wrapper-hover">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                 <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>

                  <div class="label-product">

<!-- automatisch als NEU kennzeichnen --> <?php  $now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");    $newFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getID())->getNewsFromDate(); $newToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getID())->getNewsToDate();    if($newFromDate < $now && $newToDate > $now) { ?> <span class="new_product">Neu</span> <?php } ?> <!-- -->
<!-- automatisch als SALE kennzeichnen --> <?php  $now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");    $saleFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getID())->getSaleFromDate(); $saleToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getID())->getSaleToDate();    if($saleFromDate < $now && $saleToDate > $now) { ?> <span class="sale_product">Sale</span> <?php } ?> <!-- -->
<!-- automatisch als Aktion kennzeichnen --> <?php  $now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");    $aktionFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getID())->getAktionFromDate(); $aktionToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getID())->getAktionToDate();    if($aktionFromDate < $now && $aktionToDate > $now) { ?> <span class="aktion_product">Aktion</span> <?php } ?> <!-- -->

                        <?php if($_product->getData('neu')){echo '<span class="neu">'.$this->__('neu').'</span>';  }?> 
                        <?php if($_product->getData('neu_ab')){echo '<span class="neu_ab">'.$this->__('neu_ab').'</span>';  }?>
                        <?php if($_product->getData('sale')){echo '<span class="sale">'.$this->__('Sale').'</span>';  }?>
                        <?php if($_product->getData('aktion')){echo '<span class="aktion">'.$this->__('Aktion').'</span>';  }?>
                        <?php if($_product->getData('vorfuehrbereit')){echo '<span class="vorfuehrbereit">'.$this->__('vorführbereit').'</span>';  }?>
                        <?php if($_product->getData('season')){echo '<span class="season">'.$this->__('season').'</span>';  }?>
                    </div>    
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(228); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                    <div class="product-shop">
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>

                       <div class="desc_grid"><?php $small_getDescription = strip_tags($_product->getShortDescription());
                             if (strlen($small_getDescription) < 70) echo($small_getDescription);
                             else { echo mb_substr($small_getDescription, 0, 70,'UTF-8').'...';} ?></div>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="actions">
                          <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <!-- // Warenkorb in Anfrage verändern // Start // -->
                        <?php   if($_product->getno_cart_button()){ ?> <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Anfrage') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onClick="parent.location='/kontakt'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Anfrage') ?></span></span></button></p> <?php }
                                else { ?> <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button> <?php } ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                         <!-- // Warenkorb in Anfrage verändern // ENDE // -->
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <!-- <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Details') ?>" class="button btn-details" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></span></span></button> -->
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <li><a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" rel="tooltip" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a  title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?> " href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" rel="tooltip" class="link-compare "><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--  <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
                  <div class="label-product">             
                        <?php if($_product->getData('neu')){echo '<span class="neu">'.$this->__('neu').'</span>';  }?>
                        <?php if($_product->getData('neu_ab')){echo '<span class="neu_ab">'.$this->__('neu_ab').'</span>';  }?>
                        <?php if($_product->getData('sale')){echo '<span class="sale">'.$this->__('Sale').'</span>';  }?>
                        <?php if($_product->getData('aktion')){echo '<span class="aktion">'.$this->__('Aktion').'</span>';  }?>
                        <?php if($_product->getData('vorfuehrbereit')){echo '<span class="vorfuehrbereit">'.$this->__('vorführbereit').'</span>';  }?>
                    </div> --!>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It's pretty clear that `$_product` is not an object in the code, presumably it's null - meaning "not defined". Where does `$_product` come from?

Comment: I guess, its the product that was chosen for the compare site? Honestly, I have no Idea, on the other list.phtml it worked this way.

Comment: Can you post the whole file pls?

Comment: It sounds like the $_product variable doesn't contain anything. On another note, if your attribute is named no_cart_button, your call should be $_product->getNoCartButton(). Magento has logic built in that will parse the function name into your attribute name, but not with the way you do it. However, if you want to have less functional overhead, you are better off with $_product->getData('no_cart_button'). Doesn't solve your current problem, just some helpful advice.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer there it is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in the list.phtml the code goes like

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
// show the data for $_product
// [...]
```

, the code in the compare file is like:

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item):
// show the data for $_item
// $_product? I don't know what that is
// [...]
```

You could try to do `$_item->getNoCartButton()` and see if this works.
   If it doesn't, it means that the attribute "no_cart_button" is not
   loaded for this object. You then have several options:

- first, you    should do `get_class($_item)` to know which object you're
  dealing with;    I don't think it's a product-object
- the `$_item`
  should, however, have    methods like `getProduct()` or `getProductId()`
- as soon as you have the    product, try to `getNoCartButton()` from
  that object
- if it does not work, you could do a load: `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getNoCartButton()`.
  You really shouldn't do this, though, as it will crush your performance
- you could use `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getRawAttributeValue($productId,'no_cart_button', $storeId)` which would only add a small query to your page, but still for each product you have in compare
- the best solution would be to check the Block-file and find the place where the product collection gets loaded. Then do
  `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('no_cart_button')`, which allows you
  to do something like `$_item->getProduct()->getNoCartButton()` in the
  list.phtml.

BTW, as you might have noticed, it's convention to use camel case when working with Magento. I know that `getno_cart_button()` works, but you should really use `getNoCartButton()` or `getData('no_cart_button')`.

Comment: could you pls help me, in my cms page add to cart not working -> code -> https://justpaste.it/49eqz

Comment: "not working" is not an error description. Pls ask a question here on MagentoSE with details on what is not working, which errors you get etc.

Answer (score -1):

Actually your first lines, the change from `$_product` to `$_item` an the change from `No_Cart_Button` to `NoCartButton` worked. Both changes are relevant!

Comment: Teja, why isnt it allowed to say thank you? You edited my post without any explanation.